# Separate one column into multiple ones according to words or numbers

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to spread the column from my current data frame into two columns as in the desired data frame. The current one is like that because it is scraped and it cannot be changed. I have thought on using dplyr or even regex to separate words from times but can't figure out how.

**My real data frame has real cinema names (one or two words starting with capital letter)**

The type of my current data frame column if "integer"

```
current <- data.frame(times = c("cinema1", "10:30", "12:30", "cinema2", "9:30", 
                              "16,30", "cinema3", "17:30"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
current$times <- as.integer(current$times)


desired <- data.frame(cinema = c("cinema1", "cinema1", "cinema2", "cinema2", "cinema3"), 
                     times = c("10:30", "12:30", "9:30", "16,30", "17:30"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr::fill`, we can first `replace` `times` which do not start with `"cinema"` to `NA`. Then fill the missing values and remove rows with `"cinema"` in `times`.

```
library(dplyr)

current %>%
  mutate(cinema = replace(times, !grepl("^cinema", times), NA)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(cinema) %>%
  filter(!grepl("^cinema", times))

#  times  cinema
#1 10:30 cinema1
#2 12:30 cinema1
#3  9:30 cinema2
#4 16:30 cinema2
#5 17:30 cinema3
```

**data**

```
current <- data.frame(times = c("cinema1", "10:30", "12:30", "cinema2", "9:30", 
                        "16:30", "cinema3", "17:30"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: What if my real database has real cinema names (one or two words starting with a capital letter). How would I use regex to filter those?

Comment: @InesGuardans In that case, use change the `mutate` to `mutate(cinema = replace(times, !grepl("^[[:upper:]]", times), NA)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way doing it with `dplyr` could be:

```
current %>%
 group_by(grp = cumsum(grepl("cinema", times, fixed = TRUE))) %>%
 mutate(cinema = first(times)) %>%
 filter(row_number() != 1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)

  times cinema 
  <chr> <chr>  
1 10:30 cinema1
2 12:30 cinema1
3 9:30  cinema2
4 16,30 cinema2
5 17:30 cinema3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stack` with `grepl` from `base R`

```
i1 <- grepl('cinema', current$times)
stack(setNames(split(current$times[!i1], cumsum(i1)[!i1]), current$times[i1]))
#  values     ind
#1  10:30 cinema1
#2  12:30 cinema1
#3   9:30 cinema2
#4  16,30 cinema2
#5  17:30 cinema3
```